# How to use Tomcat SSL certificate for SAML SP Meradata

Tags: tomcat, ssl, certificate, single-sign-on, spring-saml

SSL/TLS certificates in Tomcat are configured using `<Connector>` tag in `server.xml` as follows:

```
<Connector
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    port="8443" maxThreads="200"
    scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
    keystoreFile="${path.to.my.keystore.file}"
    keystorePass="${my.keystore.password}"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Resources `path.to.my.keystore.file` and `my.keystore.password` are defined in Tomcat's catalina.properties file. Project uses Spring Security SAML extension to implement SSO. Requirement is to use same certificates in SAML Service Provider (SP) metadata.

There is separate team that manages SSL/TLS certificates for Tomcat servers. They may change location of key store file or password. I would like my application to be unaffected by those changes.

I am reading above resources from `catalina.properties` file in my application using `@PropertySource("file:/path/to/catalina.properties")`. Is this approach good? Is there any better/recommended way to use same certificate configuration for TLS and SAML?

Comment: Do you want to sign the SAML messages with a TLS certificate o just use the same keystore?

Comment: I want to sign SAML messages with the TLS certificate.

Comment: Check the key usage of your certificate and rhe certification authority policy to seebif digital signature is allowed. The intended usage of a TLS certificate is server authentication, not digital signatures

Comment: Keyusage is allowed for signing.

    `KeyUsage [
      DigitalSignature
      Key_Encipherment
      Data_Encipherment
      Key_Agreement
    ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, found the answer.

Tomcat exposes properties in `catalina.properties` as system properties. So `System.getProperty()` can be used to read them.

Ref: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/index.html

> All system properties are available including those set using the -D
>   syntax, those automatically made available by the JVM and those
>   configured in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.

Secondaly, Spring SAML documentation indicates that it is possible to use SSL/TLS certificates for SAML messages signing and encryption.

Ref: [Spring SAML Certificate Configuration Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/security.html#configuration-key-management-private-keys)

> Private keys (with either self-signed or CA signed certificates) are
>   used to digitally sign SAML messages, encrypt their content and in
>   some cases for SSL/TLS Client authentication of your service provider
>   application.